# I need to make 4 squares move vertically using a loop

Tags: loops, processing

I need to make 4 individual squares that move vertically and when they touch the window edge they change directions. I can do it with one square but how do i do it with 4 to avoid repeating the loop. This has to be done in processing

Answer (score 1):

The code you are looking for looks like this (tested):

```
int x[] = new int[4];
int y[] = new int[x.length];
int s[] = new int[x.length];
int vx[] = new int[x.length];
int vy[] = new int[x.length];

void setup(){
  size(400, 400);

  for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    x[i] = round(random(width) - s[i]);
    y[i] = round(random(height) - s[i]);
    s[i] = round(random(90));
    vx[i] = round(random(-6, 6));
    vy[i] = round(random(-6, 6));
  }
}


void draw(){
  background(0);
  for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    rect(x[i], y[i], s[i], s[i]);
    x[i] += vx[i];
    y[i] += vy[i];
    if(vx[i] + x[i] > width - s[i] / 2 || vx[i] + x[i] < 0 + s[i] / 2) vx[i] *= -1;
    if(vy[i] + y[i] > height - s[i] / 2 || vy[i] + y[i] < 0 + s[i] / 2) vy[i] *= -1;
  }
}
```

To add more squares, just change the number 4 in the first line to the amount of squares you want. To change the squares presets / properties, just change what they are set to inside the for loop in the setup(). The way this works is it generates some random squares at random positions with random sizes moving with random constant velocities. the squares do not, however, collide with **each other**. If you want to know how to make them collide with each other, just ask that in a different question and rest assured I will be there to answer [:)]. Also, I can see that you are a beginner to processing. I recommend this set of playlists starting at 4.0: [processing 3 - The Coding Train](https://www.youtube.com/user/shiffman/playlists?view=50&sort=dd&shelf_id=2).